# how to use simpleitk get inverse displacement field

Tags: python, itk, simpleitk

I just moved from matlab to python recently so I can use simpleitk and sorry if this is a dumb question.

I have a transformation tx after demons registration using simpleitk. I wish to get the displacement field and its inverse by doing the following,

```
disp_field = tx.GetDisplacementField()
disp_field_inv = tx.GetInverseDisplacementField()
```

It turns out disp_field is exactly what I need --- an image volume of 256*256*176. But disp_field_inv is an empty array. Does anyone know why?

Then I tried the following,

```
disp_field_inv = sitk.InverseDisplacementField(disp_field,disp_field.GetSize(),disp_field.GetOrigin(),disp_field.GetSpacing(),
                                           subsamplingFactor=16)
```

But python is just running like forever. Does anybody know how to do it properly?

Answer (score 0):

The following is the specification for running the `InvertDisplacementField` procedural interface

```
Image itk::simple::InvertDisplacementField  (const Image & image1,
        uint32_t    maximumNumberOfIterations = 10u,
        double      maxErrorToleranceThreshold = 0.1,
        double      meanErrorToleranceThreshold = 0.001,
        bool    enforceBoundaryCondition = true)
```

So I think that by you passing the

```
disp_field.GetSize(),disp_field.GetOrigin(),disp_field.GetSpacing(), subsamplingFactor=16
```

as parameters 2 to 5 means you are passing the interface not what is expected?

Try just running `disp_field_inv = sitk.InverseDisplacementField(disp_field)`

and see if it iterates to a result!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried sitk.InverseDisplacementField(disp_field) before and it just would not converge.

Comment: Have you tried sitk.InverseDisplacementField(disp_field, 1)  i.e running it with a single iteration rather than 10?

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth after all these years, just wanted to point out that the original question and (so far only) answer by g.stevo mix-up two different filters available in SimpleITK, namely:

- `sitk.InverseDisplacementField`
- `sitk.InvertDisplacementField`

Each of these procedural APIs and their respective image filters have different `Execute` function arguments.